# How do you set a toggle button to do something when it is not selected?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am pretty new to flutter and am creating an app that uses a toggle button to mute the background music. I am having trouble figuring out how to keep the music volume set to the max when the toggle button is not selected. I thought of using some sort of else statement when after the onPressed method but I am not quite sure of where I would put that or if there is a more efficient way of doing it? Thanks in advance!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ToggleButtonExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const ToggleButtonExample({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ToggleButtonExampleState createState() => _ToggleButtonExampleState();
}

class _ToggleButtonExampleState extends State<ToggleButtonExample> {

  List<bool> _selections = List.generate(1, (index) => false);
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: ToggleButtons(children: [
          Icon(Icons.volume_off),
        ], isSelected: _selections,
          onPressed: (int index) {
            
          // Set Sound volume to 0
          
            setState(() {
              _selections[index] = !_selections[index];
            });
          },)
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: do you mean, by default music will be loud, and if i press the button it will be mute, pressing again it will be loud?

Comment: Yes, but when I press it again the music won't go back to loud it'll just stay off

Comment: it is working in my case, shoud i share mine example?

Comment: That’d be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this by creating a bool called mute and every time I click on the button it checks if it is clicked and if so it sets mute to false and so on.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ToggleButtonExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const ToggleButtonExample({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ToggleButtonExampleState createState() => _ToggleButtonExampleState();
}

class _ToggleButtonExampleState extends State<ToggleButtonExample> {
  List<bool> _selections = List.generate(1, (index) => false);

  bool mute = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: ToggleButtons(
      children: [
        Icon(Icons.volume_off),
      ],
      isSelected: _selections,
      onPressed: (int index) {
        if (mute == true) {
          homeBGM.setVolume(0);
          mute = false;
        } else if (mute == false) {
          homeBGM.setVolume(.25);
          mute = true;
        }

        setState(() {
          _selections[index] = !_selections[index];
        });
      },
    ));
  }
}
```